# c++ memory corruption detection

Tags: c++, memory-management

The code below has an obvious bug, it overruns `data2`, but it doesn't trigger a runtime error such as a crash.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory.h>

unsigned char data1[4];
unsigned char data2[4];

int main()
{
    memset(data1, 1, 4);
    memset(data2, 2, 4);

    int i;
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
        printf("%d %d\n", data1[i], data2[i]);

    data2[4] = 2;//wrong

    printf("===============================\n");
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
        printf("%d %d\n", data1[i], data2[i]);

    return 1;
}
```

output :

```
1 2
1 2
1 2
1 2
===============================
2 2   // this is a error, data1 had been changed, but not showing runtime error.
1 2
1 2
1 2
Press any key to continue
```

How can I detect errors of this type? Are there any options to make memory errors generate a warning or runtime error in gcc or visual studio?

Comment: Use a debugger to step through your program. Also, if you are using C++ (as it seems from your tag) avoid using C-style input/output.

Comment: Above code is so simple to show this kind of error. If there is a huge program made by someone and I should find the bugs, a solution for this issue will be needed.

Comment: These can be tricky. You may be able to detect it with a memory debugger like valgrind or address sanitizer.

Comment: @semenbari Why are you doing `data2[4] = 2`?

Comment: This is why iterators were invented, can't go out of range by accident with them. I avoid C code like the plague. Plus you can use std algorithms on them.

Comment: OMG. This is a intended error to show solution.

Comment: Does the edit capture your intent, semenbari?

Comment: a) static code checkers sometimes able to detect it (in particular case it would); b) dynamic code checkers; c)avoiding use of naked arrays

Comment: @semenbari *Above code is so simple to show this kind of error. If there is a huge program made by someone and I should find the bugs, a solution for this issue will be needed* -- The solution is to hope that you can find the bug and fix it   What you've posted is nothing new -- these type of bugs have always existed in C++ (and C) --  the programmer should be fully aware that these bugs are hard to find, and thus just invest the time in debugging the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I would execute the huge program you mentioned before with **valgrind** to get a detailed report of possible errors in the program.

Answer (score 1):

Your arrays have 4 elements, so valid indexes are 0..3. Writing to `data2[4]` is going out of bounds into surrounding memory, which just happens to be occupied by `data1`.  Classic buffer overflow bug.  The code has **undefined behavior**, anything could happen.